# Bluetooth client Socket get same exception everytime

Tags: android, sockets, reflection, bluetooth, kotlin

I am writing an Android app mostly in Kotlin that is supposed to scan for Bluetooth devices and also pair with them. I also want it to have a Bluetooth server socket running in the background to await connection attempts. However, I keep running into the same exception when attempting to invoke the `BluetoothSocket.connect()` method. The exception is:

```
10-10 20:07:57.917 18643-27894/com.example.zemcd.toofxchange E/Pairing Thread: error connecting

java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:754)

at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:766)

at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:388)

at com.example.zemcd.toofxchange.PairingThread.run(BluetoothUtils.kt:83)
```

I read that this could be fixed with code similar to

```
btSocket = device.javaClass.getMethod("createRFcommSocket", Int::class).invoke(device, 1) as BluetoothSocket
```

But this does not work. It causes the app to crash with a `ReflectException` caused by `NoSuchMethod`. Also I have read that this is not a published method for a reason and I would like to try to use the published `createRFcommSocketToServiceRecord()` method. I am unsure of where to go from here, or what exactly is causing the `IOException`. Also, I never even get to the pairing screen. I am trying to find what is the cause of this exception, and how to fix it. My code:

```
class BluetoothUtils {

companion object {

    val _UUID = UUID.fromString("a0e7e4c7-0e4e-43b7-9d18-659192512164")
    val TAG = "BluetoothUtils"

    fun initPairingServer(adapter: BluetoothAdapter){
        var mmServerSocket: BluetoothServerSocket? = null
        try {
            var tmp = adapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(TAG, _UUID)
            mmServerSocket = tmp
            ListenThread(mmServerSocket).start()
        }catch (ioe: IOException){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error initializing Bluetooth", ioe)
        }
    }

    fun pair(adapter: BluetoothAdapter, device: BluetoothDevice){
        var btSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null

        try {
            adapter.cancelDiscovery()
            btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(_UUID)
            PairingThread(btSocket).start()
        }catch (ioe: IOException){
            Log.e(TAG, "error connecting", ioe)
        }
    }

}
}

class ListenThread(val btServSock: BluetoothServerSocket) : Thread(){

companion object {
    val TAG = "ListenThread"
}

var btSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null

override fun run() {
    super.run()
    while (true){
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "listening . . . ")
            btSocket = btServSock.accept()
        }catch (ioe: IOException){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error", ioe) 
            break
        }

        //manage connection here
        //with either BluetoothUtils function
        //or BluetoothSocket extension
    }
}
}

class PairingThread(val btSocket: BluetoothSocket) : Thread(){

companion object {
    val TAG = "Pairing Thread"
}

override fun run() {
    super.run()

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "attempting to connect")
        btSocket.connect()
    }catch (ioe: IOException){
        Log.e(TAG, "error connecting", ioe)
        btSocket.close()
    }
}
}
```

Please somebody help me find my problem. Could it be that I'm attempting to connect to a device that isn't using the same UUID? I am just trying to connect to my laptop.